# Laravel Passport oauth/authorize требует basic auth

Tags: php, laravel, passport

Коллеги, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Установил Laravel passport. Изменение фронта на клиенте (клиент на Yii) мне недоступно, поэтому для тестирования создал там роут (назовем его /api/oauth/login), с которого делаю переадресацию на oauth-server:

```
public function actionOauthLogin()
{
    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => '12',
        'client_secret' => '',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://client.loc/api/oauth/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => '',
    ]);
    return $this->redirect('http://oauth-server.loc/oauth/authorize?' . $query);
}
```

По роуту /api/oauth/callback следующий код (строго по доке):

```
public function actionOauthCallback()
{
    $http = new Client();
    $response = $http->post('http://oauth-server.loc/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => '3',
            'client_secret' => 'TJDyfygkuga45rtyfj8&65567Yhhgjjjj',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://client.loc/api/oauth/callback',
            'code' => Yii::app()->request->getParamFromRequest('code'),
        ],
    ]);
    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
}
```

И когда я захожу по урлу /api/oauth/login меня ожидаемо перекидывает на oauth-server.loc/oauth/authorize?{параметры} но там появляется окно basic auth. Откуда оно берется и зачем - не ясно. В настройках nginx никакой basic auth не настроен. Ну а если я нажимаю "отменить" в окне базовой авторизации, то oauth-server возвращает ошибку:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

Вопрос: что я делаю не так и как надо?

Comment: php artisan passport:client --password так сделал ?

Comment: да, и в таблице oauth_clients он есть и в поле password_client у него 1

Comment: А ты все пробовал что тут советуют ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572957/laravel-passport-password-grant-client-authentication-failed

Comment: Таак. Интересно, что гугл мне этого не выплюнул. Сейчас гляну, спасибо!

Comment: нет, ничего из этого не помогло. случилась одна странность. на один единственный запрос все отработало как надо, меня перекинуло на форму авторизации. Но после ввода логина и пароля началась та же хрень

Comment: Последнее натолкнуло меня на мысль посмотреть в cookies сбросил их и снова единожды отработало правильно. Это почти успех. Нужно разбираться дальше.

Comment: Похоже лара в любой непонятной ситуации в oauth возвращает basic auth. Это странно.

Comment: Странно, не сталкивался с таким, хотя вчера у меня тоже косяк стал какой то вылазить, не пропускал csrf токен, хоть он и  был как параметр задан и в заголовках лежал, нашел решение выставив заголовки Access-Control-Allow-Origin *,Access-Control-Allow-Headers Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application, может у тебя схожая проблема ?